# Cron expression that fires when month changes. Possible through quartz expression?

Tags: jsp, servlets, cron

I am trying to make a Cron expression that would fire when the month changes from March to April. Is this possible through a Quartz expression? How?

I am working on an application that runs on a local server. So I need an expression that fires the trigger on next working day when financial year gets changed

Comment: working day means, that you also have to take care about public holidays? (can easter-holidays be so early?)

Comment: yes, because server will not run on holidays

Comment: There's a "inverted" question: http://superuser.com/questions/239591/cron-tips-for-not-running-cron-jobs-on-holidays-the-monday-of-a-three-day-weeke

maybe you can trigger a script and check there if it's a public holiday?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cronmaker.com  Check this link to generate cron expression for desired timings. you can initiate this cron expression either through Quartz api or if you are using linux ,you can directly run this through commands.